# How to split a list of lists?

Tags: python, split

I have the following output which is a list made up of three elements:

```
 ['out1    : (   83.25,    78.32)  *33.90*     2.29    2.14    0.82    65.95', 
'out2    : (  101.80,    95.10)  *31.73*    12.05    0.60    0.96   -26.46', 
'out3    : (   49.84,    42.29)  *33.19*     6.54    1.24    0.50    67.42']
```

I want to split it so it makes it one lone list made up of several elements. When I use the split function it only works on one element at a time. e.g. `num_lst = outputtest[0].split()` gives:

```
['out1', ':', '(', '83.25,', '78.32)', '*33.90*', '2.29', '2.14', '0.82', '65.95']
```

Which is what I want but only on 1/3rd of the list. How do I apply the split function to all of the elements any given list? I've tried 
`num_lst = outputtest[1:-1].split()`
 
and it gives an error stating that split does not work on list objects.

Comment: `num_lst = [i.split() for i in outputtest]` ?

Comment: `list(map(str.split, outputtest))` ?

Comment: `num_lst = outputtest[1:-1].split()` doesn't work because you're trying to split the list you'll need to select the string inside the list first like this `num_lst = outputtest[1:-1][0].split()` (replace `0` with the index you like)

Comment: @helpmeagain : You might want to accept an answer if it is the solution of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that the input is not a list of lists, but a list of strings.

Second, we basically want to split all strings and then flatten the resulting list of lists. There are multiple ways to do this, we could, for instance, use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

out = list(chain(*[s.split() for s in input]))
```

With your list of strings as input, this gives us:

```
>>> out
['out1', ':', '(', '83.25,', '78.32)', '*33.90*', '2.29', '2.14', '0.82', '65.95', 'out2', ':', '(', '101.80,', '95.10)', '*31.73*', '12.05', '0.60', '0.96', '-26.46', 'out3', ':', '(', '49.84,', '42.29)', '*33.19*', '6.54', '1.24', '0.50', '67.42']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long_list = ['out1    : (   83.25,    78.32)  *33.90*     2.29    2.14    0.82    65.95',
              'out2    : (  101.80,    95.10)  *31.73*    12.05    0.60    0.96   -26.46',
              'out3    : (   49.84,    42.29)  *33.19*     6.54    1.24    0.50    67.42']
out=[]
for i in range(len(long_list)):
    out = out + long_list[i].split()

print(out)
```